# SKNode containsPoint is not working

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a button that switches the scene. I know the code to switch the scene but the code I'm using to do it with a button isn't working.

UPDATE: I have the code working on the first scene, but when I use the same code on another scene (i switched the button and scene) it doesnt work.
anyone know why?

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let gamestartScene = GameStartScene(size: self.frame.size)
    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    if menuButton.containsPoint(location){
   self.removeChildrenInArray([menuButton,replayButton,highScoreLabel,scoreLabela])
        self.view?.presentScene(gamestartScene)
    score = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locationInNode` instead of `locationInView`

`let location = touch.locationInNode(self)`

**The origin of UIView coordinates and the SKScene coordinates are different.** The origin (0,0) of the `UIView` is at the top left. The origin of the `SKScene` is at the bottom left. So the functions `locationInNode` and `locationInView` will return different results.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if(button.containsPoint(location)) {

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: is there a way to say if touchesEnded and touchesBegan at the same location, then do something?

Comment: that really is a new question. The touch object returned is always the same for the same finger until you have lifted it off the screen in touchesEnded. You can compare them with the === operator.